# ORM - is that intrinsic part of JPA specification

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to understand ORM and JPA, have some confusion on these two terms.

I started with Hibernate initially and came to know that Hibernate is an `ORM tool` and it `implements JPA as well`.

Now it is where my doubts start.

ORM stands for Object relation mapping and JPA for Java Persistence API.

1) Is ORM a sub-specification within JPA? That is, does JPA have the specification about how to map java objects and DB rows?

2) If #1 isn't correct then what exactly is ORM and JPA taken as individual entities>

3) Many places I read Hibernate is an ORM tool and JPA implementer; but are they really different? I am getting confused on these two.

Comment: Ever considered reading the JPA spec? JPA is designed around RDBMS so *is* ORM. It is not designed for other types of datastores.

Comment: @NeilStockton: I must admit I haven't read the JPA spec as yet. But do JPA specs tell how to do mapping between objects and DB? If so, then why do we explicitly say Hibernate is ORM tool and implements JPA (if JPA implicitly imply ORM capabilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrong
2. ORM is simply a general term for frameworks/tools that helps you to map Relational DBMS records to Objects (and vice-versa), so that in your code you just work against entity objects, and the actions you performed on them are translated back to changes in RDBMS.  There are a lot of different tools doing such works, Hibernate being one of the most well-known within them.  Later Java drafted a standard called JPA to make a "standard" for such kind of ORM tools.  So JPA is a spec for (some kind of) ORM frameworks, just like JMS being spec for messaging systems.
3. I wish you understand it after reading point 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it cleared a lot of things. So, in simple words JPA is a Java community standard specification for ORM, which implementors adhere to.

Comment: Yup. And there are ORM framework that does not implement JPA too, such as Mybatis (though I am a bit skeptical to call it an ORM :P )